# Difference between “нac" и "наш”

Tags: местоимения

I was given this sentence:
Our names are Misha and Masha
They told me to translate it and i translated it like this:
*Наш* зовут Миша и Маша 
But the correct answer:
*Нас* зовут Миша и Маша
Why is нас(us) used in this case instead of наш(our)?

Comment: I'm always saying that difference between whom and who is a rare example of English language feature that easier to grasp to a Russian speaker rather than English-only speaker )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The literal translation of the phrase **"Нас зовут Миша и Маша"** is not **"Our names are Misha and Masha"**, but **"We are called Misha and Masha"**. I.e. **"зовут"** is a verb.

And so "we are called" = "**нас** зовут" (It's like "They call **us**")

If it was said **"Наши имена Миша и Маша"** (it's literal translation of **"Our names are Misha and Masha"**) then it would be "Our names" = "**Наши** имена" (BTW, plural **"Наши"**, not singular **"Наш"**).